# iOS 7 issue with tableview cell when returning to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a weird bug that only happens on iOS 7 and not iOS 8, i'm using the latest XCode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 sdk with Swift.

The tableview gets displayed without problems when the view controller gets loaded, i proceed to click on any row and a viewcontroller gets presented as a modal view. The problem happens when i dismiss this modal view controller, the cell that i initially selected to open this view gets wiped and replaced by the prototype cell values, it doesn't retain the row information.

here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIs6w.jpg (i don't have enough reputation to show the image within this post)

here's the code where i present the modal view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PinAgendaCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinAgendaItemTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.ror

    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popupviewcontroller") as? PopupViewController

    controller?.listaItem = listaItemsFiltrados[row]

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller!)
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here's the custom uitableviewcell (named PinAgendaItemTableViewCell) class code for displaying data on the rows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bordeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var pinImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstLineLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLineLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cursoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var asignaturaLabel: UILabel!

var listaItem: ListaItem? {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI() {
    if(listaItem != nil) {
        firstLineLabel.text = listaItem?.firstLine != nil ? "\(listaItem!.firstLine!) (\(listaItem!.typeName!))" : ""
        secondLineLabel.text = listaItem?.secondLine != nil ? listaItem?.secondLine : ""
        dateLabel.text = listaItem?.date
        cursoLabel.text = "\(listaItem!.descCurso)"
        if listaItem!.descCurso.isEmpty {
            cursoLabel.text = ""
        }
        asignaturaLabel.text = "\(listaItem!.descAsignatura)"
        if listaItem!.descAsignatura.isEmpty {
            asignaturaLabel.text = ""
        }
        pinImageView.image = UIImage(named: listaItem!.icon!)
        pinImageView.image = pinImageView.image!.imageWithColor(Fn.hexStringToUIColor(listaItem!.typeColor!))
        bordeView.backgroundColor = Fn.hexStringToUIColor(listaItem!.typeColor!)
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: Can we see the complete code from your main view controller? Do you have anything set in your `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: thanks for the fast responses, i found out how to solve the issue, on iOS 7 the cell has to be initialized like this cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell and not with the iOS method which includes the forIndexPath argument